# how to Inherit components?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Is it possible to inherit components such as jTextField, jComboBox etc in a different class?

```
if(!(jButton7.isEnabled()))
        {

            if((getTotal==enterPounds))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n"+jTextPane1.getText());

                int x = jList1.getSelectedIndices()[0];
                int i = Integer.parseInt(stringssssss[x]);
                int oook= Integer.parseInt(seats);

                i=i-oook;
                stringssssss[x]= stringssssss[x]= ""+i;
                jTextField8.setText(""+ stringssssss[x]);           
            }
```

the above code is in g.java, can i transfer this to another class and call the method in g.java?

Comment: Yes, just make the method public in g.java.  This technique is called Encapsulation.

Comment: JSomething are meant to be used as-are, _not_ extended. Nothing in your snippet that extends (aka: inherit), btw.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to inherit (members, methods?) and what your exact plan is... More details please?

Answer (score 1):

You could call this code from another class, say if you wrapped the code in a method such as below.

```
public void setText() {
if(!(jButton7.isEnabled()))
        {

            if((getTotal==enterPounds))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n"+jTextPane1.getText());

                int x = jList1.getSelectedIndices()[0];
                int i = Integer.parseInt(stringssssss[x]);
                int oook= Integer.parseInt(seats);

                i=i-oook;
                stringssssss[x]= stringssssss[x]= ""+i;
                jTextField8.setText(""+ stringssssss[x]);           
            }
}
}
```

Then in another class do

```
private R r = new R();
r.setText();
```

If you wanted to actually inherit the variables from R, make them protected in R and then write a new class that extends R.  These variables will then be available to this new class.

Comment: possible but nothing you should nor want to do